# How to iterate list object which is store in application scope using jstl forEach tage

Tags: java

I'm trying to iterate an ArrayList object which is stored in applicationScope(ServletContext) in my jsp page using jstl forEach tag, but its not iterating

```
<select name="">
<option value="">Select country</option>
<c:forEach items="${applicationScope.countriesList}" item="country">
<option value="<c:out value="${country.countryID}"/>"><c:out        value="${country.countryName}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but its not iterating"? Is the list `applicationScope.countriesList` not empty? Does the list even exist? Does `applicationScope` exists?

Comment: It's not empty, when i write the same code in jsp using scriptlet tags and expression tags its showing the countries list in dropdown, but when i'm using jstl forEach tag it's displaying nothing in drowdown. that's the my problem